# Jquery can not repeat animation - Impossible exercise

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have an animation script. I want to infinite repeat it. But setInterval is not working with my script.

Here is my code:

```
function waw_animation(){
$("#first").animate({left: "0px"}, 1000);
$("#first").delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#second").delay(2000).animate({right: '0px'}, 1000);
$("#second").show(500);
$("#second").delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#third").delay(5000).animate({right: '0px'}, 1000);
$("#third").show(500);
$("#third").delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#fourth").delay(8000).animate({left: "0px"}, 1000);
$("#fourth").delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#fifth").delay(11000).animate({left: "0px"}, 1000);
$("#fifth").delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#sixth").delay(14000).animate({right: '0px'}, 1000);
$("#sixth").show(500);
$("#sixth").delay(2000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#seventh").delay(18000).animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
$("#eighth").delay(19000).animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
$("#nineth").delay(20000).animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
$("#seventh").delay(3000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#eighth").delay(3000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#nineth").delay(3000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#tenth").delay(26000).animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000);
$("#tenth").delay(10000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){ waw_animation(); }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Is it me, or i don't see the setInterval here?

Comment: Here is not setInterval but if I put in setInterval the code is not working...

Comment: Like `$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function(){ waw_animation(); }, 1000);
});`

Comment: Ok, so without the `setInterval` your code only executes once.  Does the single call to `waw_animation()` provide your expected result?  If not, then provide markup into your question as well.

Comment: Yes, without setInterval my code is perfect. But I don't want to play it once. It have to be infinite.

Comment: If I use just `waw_animation();` it works perfect too. But the code only executes once.

Comment: Ok, well I don't see anything inherently wrong with your code.  Can you post your markup as well?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
The code say:

```
$("#first").delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
$("#second").delay(2000).animate({right: '0px'}, 1000);
```

But if the function is restarting the opacity and the absolute right position isn't setting back.

THE SOLUTION IS:

```
#first,
#second,
#third,
.
.
.
#tenth
```

This elements has two class:

```
.from-left
or
.from-right
```

I put this lines front of my function:

```
$(".from-right").hide();
$(".from-left").css("left", "-100%");
$(".from-left").css("opacity", "1");
$(".from-right").css("right", "-100%");
$(".from-right").css("opacity", "1");
```